# How to make a dynamic menu using data from a http get in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, axios

I am using axios to make a get in my URL that sends me this:

```
{
  "companies": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Fernando"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "description": "Paulo"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "description": "Junior"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "description": "Lucio"
    }
  ]
}
```

my axios code looks like this:

```
axios.get("MY URL").then((response) => {
this.setState({
      data: response.data.companies
    });
      data = response.data
  console.log(response.data)
  console.log("data change",this.state.data)

})
```

I can get the object that i need in my state or in a var, this is what shows in the console, it seems that the object is right:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{id: 1, description: "Fernando"}
1
:
{id: 2, description: "Paulo"}
2
:
{id: 3, description: "Junior"}
3
:
{id: 4, description: "Lucio"}
length
:
4
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Now i need to create a menu that will render 4 options that i have in my object, so how can i render this without knowing how many itens i will have in this object? I already tried .map but this is an object with arrays inside and map does not work on that. The solution i'm after is something that can iterate over the array and render the menus.
I'm kind of loss with this axios.

Comment: Why does `.map()` not work? The info you provided clearly states that your `response.data.companies` is an `array` and even your `console.log` output shows an array, so after your `setState()` you should easily be able to `this.state.data.map(function() {})` to render your items

Comment: should work, can you edit with the component you are trying to display

Comment: When i try to use .map it says that .map is no a function

Comment: i will appreciate if someone can go in a chat with me, so i clan explain better  what i want to do and why is not working

Answer (score 0):

The following will generate N number of div elements for your data array:

```
var items = Array.from({length: $this.state.data.length}, (_, i) => i)
     .map(i => <div key={"item" + i}>{$this.state.data[i]}</div>);
```

Comment: As this is not compatible with Internet Explorer, see the suggested [**Polyfill**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) if you need to run it on IE.

Comment: and how can i render this?

Comment: what do you mean? render() { return <div>{items}</div>;}

Comment: can u invite me to chat so i can explain better?

Comment: @Nope, good point, I thought that babel is sort of standard when you use React, no?

Comment: @LucioZenir, I guess I invited you. Could you please check: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165650/react-rendering-menu-items
I am not very fluent with chats here yet.

Comment: @AndriiNikolaienko No idea I don't work with react but in general I like to know how things are done before they are done for me :)